# dpkg Error: libc6-i386 half-installed

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I'm new to Ubuntu, installed Ubuntu 15.10 on my new laptop and everything seems to work fine, but …

Every time I try to install or deinstall something from softwarecenter (or via apt-get) this Error occurs (sorry it is in german):

```
Trigger für libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) werden verarbeitet ...
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 libc6-i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I searched for similar questions and tried

```
apt-get autoclean
```

```
apt-get autoremove
```

and also tried to reinstall libc6-i386, it seems it is only half-installed (?)

```
$sudo apt-get install libc6-i386
libc6-i386 ist schon die neueste Version.
0 aktualisiert, 0 neu installiert, 0 zu entfernen und 0 nicht aktualisiert.
1 nicht vollständig installiert oder entfernt.
Es müssen noch 0 B von 2.272 kB an Archiven heruntergeladen werden.
Nach dieser Operation werden 0 B Plattenplatz zusätzlich benutzt.
Möchten Sie fortfahren? [J/n] j
dpkg: Fehler beim Bearbeiten des Paketes libc6-i386 (--configure):
 Paket libc6-i386 ist nicht bereit zur Konfiguration
 kann nicht konfiguriert werden (momentaner Status »half-installed«)
Fehler traten auf beim Bearbeiten von:
 libc6-i386
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I don't know what to do next, just reinstall the whole system?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`»half-installed«` packages should be re-installed. Only one command:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libc6-i386
```

Comment: worked for a dpkg-dev half-installed error as well - thanks